# Jquery window size. change css class with text character limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have three different responsive: 
Large Monitor min-width: 1200px
Small Monitor (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)
Tablet (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)

I'm trying to use the below code to change character limit for the above three screen sizes. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/soulsurfer/5SM9u/30/

```
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1280) {
        $("#limit-char").each(function(i){
        len=$(this).text().length;
           if(len>30)
            {
              $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,30)+'...');
            }
        })
    } 
}

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Comment: Your fiddle works. It changes the background color and limits the number of characters.

Comment: What type of element is `#limit-char`? Is it an `input`? If so maybe you can use the `[maxlength]` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example for you here http://jsfiddle.net/5SM9u/32/

```
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 700) {
        $('#menu2').addClass('f-nav');
        $("#menu2").each(function(i){
        len=$(this).text().length;
           if(len>30)
            {
              $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,30)+'...');
            }
        })
    } else{
        $('#menu2').removeClass('f-nav');
        $("#menu2").each(function(i){
        $(this).text($(this).data('originalTxt'));
        });
    }
}
$("#menu2").each(function(){
        $(this).data({originalTxt: $(this).text()});
});
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Width is set to 700 for testing purpose. You can change it for you implementation.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Mr. Shahzad, this script worked as I wanted with the browser, but when I use an ipad to view the page its not limiting the characters, even those on web browser smaller sizes works well. What could be the reason that it's not working?

Comment: Check if the $(window).width() is returning the expected value?

Comment: on the script I've set "< 1270" and it seems like its working when I resize the browser on the desktop computer. But when I open it on the iPad its not limiting the characters. Javascript is enabled on the iPad so it should work. but no i still haven't figured whats happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You can on load save full text in variable and in your function make three `if`

```
var defaultString=$("#menu2").text();
function checkWidth() {

    if($(window).width()>1200){
        $('#menu2').removeClass('f-nav').removeClass("f-nav-small");
        $("#menu2").each(function(i){
        len=$(this).text().length;
           if(len>30)
            {
              $(this).text(defaultString);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    if ($(window).width() > 991 && $(window).width()<1200 ) {
        $('#menu2').addClass('f-nav');
        $("#menu2").each(function(i){
        len=$(this).text().length;
           if(len>30)
            {
              $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,30)+'...');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    if($(window).width()<992){
        $('#menu2').removeClass("f-nav").addClass('f-nav-small');
        $("#menu2").each(function(i){
        len=$(this).text().length;
           if(len>10)
            {
              $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,10)+'...');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

}
checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```